# Initialization of a variable by a function in initialization list

Tags: c++, struct

Lets suppose I have the following example struct with a constructor

```
struct CAddition {
    int x;
    int y;
    int c;
    int result() { 
        return x + y; 
    }
    CAddition();
    ~CAddition();
};

CAddition::CAddition()
    :x(0)
    ,y(0)
{
    c = result();
}
```

Now if want to initialize `c` in the above way it works, but what if I want to initialize my c in within the initialization list something like

```
, c(result())
```

it shows a correct result somehow, but is it a correct syntax ? can I face some problems?

Comment: That's C++, not C -- fixed it for you.

Comment: sorry I clicked on the tag quickly , thanks :)

Comment: *"it shows a correct result somehow"* - Why shouldn't it?

Comment: As long as `c` is initialised (which really means declared) after any other members `result()` uses, why would there ever be a problem? Methods themselves do not need initialised; whether they are valid to use during initialisation only depends on whether/which members they need to access (well, if they're not virtual, that is...)

Comment: @StoryTeller i tried it for a simple example but the code which i have has big nested structures for which i am creating new constructors , thought if there is a possibility it would break the code if this syntax is wrong

Comment: @Robert - The syntax isn't wrong (or it wouldn't even build). There is a possible problem that may happen, but compilers are good at warning you about it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a60d298e1394d91f